# Reading and processing multiple text files

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I've tried to create a program that will read multiple text files in a certain directory and then produce a frequency of the words that appear in all the text files.

Example

> text file 1: hello my name is john hello my
>
> text file 2: the weather is nice the weather is

The output would show

> hello 2
>
> my 2
>
> name 1
>
> is 3
>
> john 1
>
> the 2
>
> weather 2
>
> nice 1

The issue i'm having is that my program just terminates as soon as it's ran, no output is shown at all.

Here's my class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCountstackquestion implements Runnable {

    public String filename;

    public WordCountstackquestion(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void run() {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files\\1.txt");

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            Scanner in = null;

            for (File files : file.listFiles()) {
                int count = 0;
                try {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    in = new Scanner(file);

                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        String word = in.next();

                        if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                            map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            map.put(word, 1);
                        }
                        count++;

                    }
                    System.out.println(file + " : " + count);

                    for (String word : map.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(word + " " + map.get(word));
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(file + " was not found.");
                }
            }
        }
    //in.close();
    }
}
```

Here's my class to run them

```
public class Mainstackquestion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            for (String filename : args) {                          
                CheckFile(filename);
            }
        }
        else {
            CheckFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files\\1.txt"); 
        }
   }

    private static void CheckFile(String file) {
        Runnable tester = new WordCountstackquestion(file);
        Thread t = new Thread(tester);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you are importing, just use: import java.io.*; and import java.util.*;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** answer. I was wrong on the original cause of the problem. The problem was more an algorithm problem than a thread-related problem.

Code for `Mainstackquestion` class:

```
public class Mainstackquestion {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           List<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<>();

           if(args.length > 0) {
               for (String filename : args) {
                   Thread t = CheckFile(filename);
                   allThreads.add(t);  // We save this thread for later retrieval
                   t.start(); // We start the thread
               }
           }
           else {
               Thread t = CheckFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files"); 
               allThreads.add(t);
               t.start();               
           }

           try {
               for (Thread t : allThreads) {
                   t.join(); // We wait for the completion of ALL threads
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

     private static Thread CheckFile(String file) {
         Runnable tester = new WordCountstackquestion(file);
         return new Thread(tester);
     }
}
```

Code for `WordCountstackquestion`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCountstackquestion implements Runnable {

    public String filename;

    public WordCountstackquestion(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void run() {
        File dir = new File(filename);

        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            Scanner in = null;

            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                    int count = 0;
                    try {
                        in = new Scanner(file);
                        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                            String line = in.nextLine();
                            String[] words = line.split(" ");

                            for (String w : words) {
                                if (map.containsKey(w)) {
                                    map.put(w, map.get(w) + 1);
                                } else {
                                    map.put(w, 1);
                                }
                            }
                            count++;

                        }

                        //System.out.println(file + " : " + count);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println(file + " was not found.");
                    } finally {
                        if (in != null) {
                            in.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (String word : map.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(word + " " + map.get(word));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with the same 2 files that you gave as example.

Obtained result:

> the 2
>
> name 1
>
> weather 2
>
> is 3
>
> john 1
>
> hello 2
>
> my 2
>
> nice 1

Comment: Thanks but I didn't think my issue was in my Mainstackquestion class I think it was in my WordCountstackquestion class.

Comment: Except for your imports (see the  comment of @Henri), your `WordCountstackquestion` class seems fine to me. Did you test with my code? Also modify your imports and tell me what it gives you ;-)

Comment: I tested your code but I got an error "Unhandled exception type InterruptedException" on the line t.join()

Comment: My bad, I didn't catch the exception. I've updated my answer. If it is still not working, my guess is that either `file.isDirectory()` returns `false` or `file.listFiles()` does not return any result and therefore your program is exiting without reading any file at all.

Comment: Yeah  changing my code to yours still just terminates the program and outputs nothing. That;s why I think the issue is to do with my `WordCountstackquestion` class.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I believe that the problem comes when you create the file `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files\\1.txt");`. In this case, it is a file and not a directory so `file.isDirectory()` is always `false` and your program does not read any file at all. Can you check?

Comment: Yes `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files\\1.txt");` is a file and not a directory, if I try `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\files");` I get the catch file not found exception in my code.

Comment: OK I added the code for the other class. The problem is that your were mixing `files` and `file` variables and not using `filename` at all.

Comment: While I think that fixed my issue I now have errors on lines for lines 20 and 17. `The method exists() is undefined for the type String` , also your code has a weird error with the declaration of count? `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable` if I move count outside the enhanced for loop I don't get the error?

Comment: OK so I tested the code for the updated answer and this time it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you massively, you've put a lot of effort into this and I appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome @M33tM03! And thanks for the accepted answer! ;-)